# My chrome extension content script is multiplying same function that is send from popup.js

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, message-passing

I was trying to send input data from the popup.html to content.js. after may try i was able to send the data but when I test it. it starts executing the onmessage.listener one time when I run it again it run 2 time and it's increasing everytime.

pop.js

```
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', test);

function test() {

        let params = {
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true
        }
        chrome.tabs.query(params, gotTab);

        function gotTab(tabs) {
            //send a message to content script
            //let message = userinput.value();
            var frequest = document.getElementById('friendrequest').value;
            var ftime = document.getElementById('timedelay').value;
            var fkeyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
            let msg = {
                txt: frequest, txt1:ftime , txt2: fkeyword

            }

            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg);

        }

        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: "content.js"
    });


    }
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log(message.txt);
   x = message.txt
   if (x != "") {
    console.log("worked");
   } else {
    alert("not worked");
   }
});
```

Comment: Everytime you run `test()` you are injecting a new content script in the page, which adds a new message listener. Therefore, the number of responses increases with every listener.

Comment: So how to bypass this issue?

Comment: Either inject the content script only once, or check if it's already injected before adding a new listener, but there are probably more ways to do it.